# Xilinx SDK (Eclipse) project command line build

Tags: eclipse, batch-file, command-line, sdk, xilinx

I have an Xilinx SDK workspace with:
- hardware specification (hw);
- board support package (bsp);
- C-language application.

In other words, it is no need to create an workspace like described here http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx14_3/SDK_Doc/reference/sdk_u_commandline.htm.

Provided Xilinx SDK is an Eclipse-based IDE, how can I make Eclipse to run project clean and release|debug|all configurations build from command line/batch file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This link really helps

http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx14_1/SDK_Doc/reference/sdk_u_commandline.htm

about headlessbuild syntax:
https://www.cct.lsu.edu/~rguidry/eclipse-doc36/org/eclipse/cdt/managedbuilder/internal/core/HeadlessBuilder.html

script contents

```
set XILINX_EDK=c:\Xilinx\14.3\ISE_DS\EDK\
set XILINX=c:\Xilinx\14.3\ISE_DS\ISE\
set ECLIPSE=%XILINX_EDK%eclipse\nt\eclipse\eclipsec.exe
set WSPACE=%CD%
set VM=%XILINX%java6\nt\jre\bin\
set BSP=%CD%\TEST_bsp\
set BSPNAME=TEST_bsp
set APP=%CD%\TEST\
set APPNAME=TEST

%ECLIPSE% -vm %VM% -nosplash -application org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.headlessbuild -cleanBuild all -data %WSPACE%
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have the workspace already, can you not just run `make clean; make` in the project directory?